# UITableView with .xib cell with error : failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have create table cell with .xib file. and added in the UITableView using following code :

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DesplayCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"desplayCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DisplayCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"desplayCell"];
    }

   //
 return cell;
}
```

App crashes with error :

> failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource

Comment: Make sure the cell in your storyboard or XIB file has the same identifier `desplayCell `.

Comment: Yup both are same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget to add `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in your code.

**dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier usage**

> You should use the same reuse identifier for all cells of the same form.
>   The reuse identifier is associated with those cells (rows) of a table view that have the same general configuration, minus cell content.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DesplayCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"desplayCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DisplayCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"desplayCell"];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"desplayCell"];
    }

   //
 return cell;
```

}

Comment: You should register cell in "viewdidload" and make a resusable cell dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier 
                                                   forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. as following function returns a reusable table-view cell object for the specified reuse identifier and adds it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

In viewDidLoad write below code

```
  [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DisplayCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"desplayCell"];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath you can write below

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        DesplayCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"desplayCell"];

          if (cell == nil) { // if cell is nil then you can alloc it

       cell=[[DesplayCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"desplayCell"];

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"desplayCell"];

        }

 return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is like [Siddhesh Mhatre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5094664/siddhesh-mhatre) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42739560/2721547) But you should make a category of UITableView, it's useful for a large project.

**UITableView+Category.h**

```
- (id)dequeueReusableOrRegisterCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (id)dequeueReusableOrRegisterCellWithClass:(Class)aClass;
```

**UITableView+Category.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableOrRegisterCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell) {
        [self registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:identifier bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:identifier];
        cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableOrRegisterCellWithClass:(Class)aClass{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(aClass)];

    if (!cell) {
        [self registerClass:aClass forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(aClass)];
        cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(aClass)];
    }

    return cell;
}
```